# Tails: How to keep browser add-ons in persistent storage?

Tags: browser, persistence, tails-os

(Yes, I know [I should not install browser add-ons](https://tails.boum.org/support/faq/index.en.html#index12h2) but I know what I'm doing.)

I want to install a browser add-on ([Metamask](https://metamask.io/) Ethereum wallet) and make [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) remember it in the persistent storage. I already made the setting that browser bookmarks and dotfiles should be saved in persistent. And it also works for the bookmarks but not for the add-ons. After reboot, they're completely gone.

So how can I keep installed browser add-ons in Tails?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know that's not possible. It will probably never become possible (at least not easily) for the reasons you mentioned. Tails is designed with fingerprint resemblance in mind and allowing users to install browser plugins would be against that philosophy.

Consider using a more standard OS that supports those features, like Debian. [Tor](https://wiki.debian.org/TorBrowser) is available for all distros after-all.

Comment: Well, the other thing is whether you could write a persistent script that adds the extensions to the browser automatically. Not exactly what was asked for, but it may reduce the pain.